# Meteor iron:router - weird no routes defined

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I have a meteor 1.5 application which had no problems last night, everything worked just fine, all routes defined by iron:router were working. Today, out of nowhere and without changing any code, i have this weird error page of iron:router saying that i have no routes defined.

I have done some research and found out that the latest version of iron:router have some conflicts and it causes problems, some suggested that i downgrade iron:router, i have done that but it didn't work.

i even tried removing all my routes and putting one simple route for the homepage with url " **/** " but still get the same error page

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is it feasible to just use flow router?

Comment: i would also suggest switching to another, maintained, router as iron-router at this stage is not maintained any more. So if you want to keep updating meteor I would suggest a switch!

Comment: Try `meteor reset` and start our server again

Comment: i'll try switching to flow router, why is iron:router not maintained anymore ? most of the learning tutorials for meteor and the meteor in action book use iron:router, too bad it's not maintained anymore, it is very cool and easy to learn

Comment: meteor reset didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This message was also encountered by users when Chrome moved from version 50 to 51. Have you tried different browsers to see if the issue is specific to a certain vendor? ([git topic](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1538))

Rgs, Paul